# do-while loop into for loop

Tags: c, loops

I made a game but didn't wanted to use do-while loops.
So instead I tried to use for loops. The problem is when I run with do-while
it works but when I run with for loops it doesn't work in the same way.

I think I changed do-while into for loops correctly. Can someone let me know what I am missing?

```
    do {
        crntShowBottle = rand() % 2 + 2;
    } while (crntShowBottle == prevShowBottle);
    prevShowBottle = crntShowBottle;



    for (;;) 
    {
        crntShowBottle = rand() % 2 + 2;
        if (crntShowBottle == prevShowBottle)
                break;
    } 
    prevShowBottle = crntShowBottle;
```

Comment: The two exit conditions are completely opposite. The first loop exits when the values are not equal whilst the second one exits when they are equal.

Comment: ^^^ Correction: `if (crntShowBottle != prevShowBottle) break;`

Comment: And why do you want to change from `do/while` to `for` anyway? One is not inherently better than the other and in this case the `do/while` seems clearer anyway.

Comment: Whenever you have or see code like `for (;;) ` you should *immediately* be thinking, "Perhaps this is not really a case for a `for` loop?"

Comment: Sorry guys. I study C language just for Golang even though I studied C earliest. I kinda have faith that there's only one type of loop. So I try to use only one loop which is for loop, just as Golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to understand the mechanism of `loop` and how they are different from `do-while loop` and `for loop`.

Based on your code, what is happening!

1. In the `do-while` section, you are giving instructions that "first do something" and then checking the condition. If the condition (checking) is `true` `crntShowBottle == prevShowBottle` then the loop must run again. Otherwise, if the condition is `false` `crntShowBottle != prevShowBottle` the loop must terminate.
2. In the `for loop` section, you used the `infinite loop` `for(;;)`. Means loop will be running infinite times. But, inside the `loop` you wrote `the break` condition. So, when the condition is matching `crntShowBottle == prevShowBottle` your loop is shutting down. So, you must use `crntShowBottle != prevShowBottle`
3. You also need to understand, how `break` works!